# How trigger AsyncSelect to reload options in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two AsyncSelect components to select a category and a subcategory. When we choose a category from the first AsyncSelect, I need to load it's sub-categories to the second one.

AsyncSelect loads the items when it gets mounted. But how can I trigger it programmatically (When I select the category from the first AsyncSelect) to load the data (The subcategories to the second AsyncSelect) when it is already mounted?

```
 <AsyncSelect
    cacheOptions
    loadOptions={this.loadSubCategories}
    defaultOptions
    onInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
 />
```

Answer (score 13):

Add the key into your subCategories's asyncSelect.

```
<AsyncSelect
    key={this.state.categoryName}
    cacheOptions
    loadOptions={this.loadSubCategories}
    defaultOptions
    onInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
 />
```

When you select the category, please change the state.

```
this.setState({categoryName: "Different NAME HERE"})
```

Comment: @sumedhe, above one, is a working example. Please add the different keys in your categories. Then it will load sub-categories when you select the categories.

Comment: Excellent answer! Just to let it even clearer, you don't need to add any new state at all. Remember you can use as a key some unique information that you already have on the base category state. In my case, the base category already have an id, so I used this. Now, when the base category changes, it changes the current state, therefore the key for the subcategory also changes, and it gets rerendered.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can not load  on the basis of other triggers.
as given in document: 
[defaultOption](https://react-select.com/async#defaultoptions)

There are `two` valid values for `defaultOptions` property.

1)`Providing an option array to this prop will populate the initial set of options` (`this does the job for categories`) and

2) `filtering the options (typing in the control). Providing the prop by itself (or with 'true') tells the control to immediately fire the remote request,` (this is only happen in the same `<AsyncSelect/>`)

and your requirement is not meet to load `<AsyncSelect/>` for subcategory

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I have written the login in this.loadOptions function. How can I trigger AsyncSelect to fetch them using that function? I tried by setting defaultOptions={true} also.

Comment: I have modified my answer

Comment: Thanks Navin, your example works. But I need trigger loading the data programmatically. Without typing in the text area of AsyncSelect. Is there a way for that?

Comment: can you give a situation by updating your question? didn't get programmatically when you wanted to modify your option

Comment: There are two AsyncSelect. Let's assume them for categories and sub-categories. When we choose a category from the first AsyncSelect, I need to load it's sub-categories to the second one.